# MATLAB optimizing fitting function calls

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

I have a 3D array of dimensions (rows x cols x 8). For each element in the first two dimensions I have 8 values along the third dimension which I must fit to an equation such as exponential, polynomial etc. I have written code for this function, and I'm currently producing my output by looping over the first two dimensions, as follows:

```
for i=1:rows
    for j=1:cols
        outputArray(i,j) = functionHandle(inputArray(i,j,1:8));
    end
end
```

Can I somehow use bsxfun, arrayfun, or some other vectorization method to get rid of the for loops, so that I generate my output using something like this?

```
outputArray = bsxfun(@functionHandle,inputArray)
```

Adding the functionHandle

```
function output = functionHandle(xData,yData)
    ft = fittype( 'a*exp(-b*x)+c','independent', 'x','dependent','y' );
    opts = fitoptions( 'Method', 'NonlinearLeastSquares' );
    opts.Algorithm = 'Trust-Region';
    opts.Display = 'Off';
    opts.MaxFunEvals = 100;
    opts.MaxIter = 100;
    opts.Robust = 'LAR';
    opts.Lower = [-Inf 0 -Inf];
    opts.StartPoint = [0.35 0.05 0.90];

    % Fit model to data.
    [FitResult,~] = fit(xData,yData,ft,opts);
    output = FitResult.a;
end
```

Comment: The answer entirely depends on wether your function (`functionHandle`) is vectorized or not. You should write that function so that it allows `R`x`C`x`8` input and produces `R`x`C`x`N` output, where `N` is the number of fit parameters. That is, vectorization has to be done within the function; it cannot be done outside. From the outside you can only use the function in a loop. Note that `arrayfun` is similar, and has comparable performance, to a `for` loop

Comment: That is what I was dreading. Even so, how would you vectorize that? I would need to call some fit function RxC times and the only way I can think of is by using a for loop. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: The only way I see is to modify the internal workings of `functionHandle`, which I assume is a function you wrote. You should explain what that function does, maybe post (the relevant part of) its current code, and perhaps someone can find a way to vectorize it

Comment: I added the `functionHandle` code snippet. Many thanks. Also, sorry, I meant if you posted your first comment as an answer, I'll accept it, since that answers the question as I'd originally asked, and really I don't see how I can vectorize `functionHandle`.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll post it then. Since you are using `fit`, it seems you cannot vectorize, because `fit` takes one set of inputs at a time and produces the corresponding output

Comment: Do you want to vectorize this because it is a performance bottleneck in your code, or because you heard that loops are slow in MATLAB? Loops used to be slow 20 years ago, but this idea somehow still lingers.

Comment: It is a performance bottleneck in my code. My `inputArray` is actually an image and I want an output map representing the coefficient. Even a relatively tiny `256`x`256` image takes about 2 hours to compute, and I have `1024`x`1024` images also I need to run.

Comment: Then maybe change your fitting function: you're using non-linear least squares, and a series of options that (to my untrained eye) seem rather expensive. Also, using an anonymous function instead of a string is likely to be more efficient: `ft = fittype(@(a,b,c,x) a*exp(-b*x)+c)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer entirely depends on whether your function is vectorized or not. What you should do is write that function so that it allows `R`×`C`×`8` input and produces `R`×`C`×`N` output, where `N` is the number of fit parameters.

That is, vectorization has to be done *within* the function; it cannot be done outside. From the outside you can only use the function in a loop. Note that [`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) is similar, and has comparable performance, to a [`for`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html) loop.

Since your function basically uses[`fit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html), it seems you cannot vectorize, because `fit` takes *one* set of inputs at a time and produces the corresponding output.